# jQuery .each and height of div

Tags: jquery, height, each

I have construction like this:

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to find the highest div with class set to b in each div class set to a, and display in alert?

Comment: do you want to learn height div class="a" ? or b?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/, http://api.jquery.com/class-selector, http://api.jquery.com/height/ -- Try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.a').each(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.b', this).each(function() {
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
         maxHeight = $(this).height();  
        }
    });
    alert(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: It works great, but how to set local maximum height for each class b in clas a? Alert shows a correct value.

Comment: Just add `$('.b', this).height(maxHeight)` (where the `alert` currently is) - working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RZzTv/

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to produce a jQuery object (in this case it is effectively an array of numbers) containing the height of each matching element. You can then [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) that array to [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to determine the largest value in it:

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, ​$(".b").map(function () {
    return $(this).height(); 
}));
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EgFpK/1/).

---

**Update** (this one should behave exactly as you specify in your question)

```
$("div.a").each(function () {
    alert(Math.max.apply(Math, ​$("div.b", this).map(function () {
        return $(this).height(); 
    })));
});
```

Here's another [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/EgFpK/3/).

Comment: Since the question says "in each div class set to a", that selector should be `$('.a').find('.b')`.

Comment: @spinningarrow or simply `$('.a > .b')`

Comment: Re-reading the question, I think the OP actually wants separate results, one for each `.a` element. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @nbrooks: Well, yes. However, Sizzle works from right to left and the child selector is actually about 70% **slower** than using `.find()`. [This place](http://addyosmani.com/jqprovenperformance/) has some pretty good information on jQuery performance.

Comment: @spinningarrow Thanks for that link, didn't know that. I just figured the css selectors always outperformed the jQuery methods that didn't rely on native methods. Good to know!